# Why doesn't Thread work in this case?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

The following function is supposed to pick the element of the list with highest weight, i.e., with `Thread [f[{{a,1},{b,2}}]]` it should make the variables `initialvls={b,2}`, `m=2`.

```
initialvls = {};
m = 0;
f[x_] := Module[{},
  If[x[[2]] > m,
    m = x[[2]];
    initialvls = x
    ];
  ]
```

I dont know anything about the inner workings of mathematica. But I would expect the thread to apply first `f` to `{a,1}`,and put `m=1`, and `initialvls={a,1}`. Afterwards it would apply `f` to {b,2}, and so on... However, my function doesn't seem to do what I want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about, from your other question, `initialvls = First@Cases[#, {_, Max@#[[All, 2]]}] &@{{a, 1}, {b, 2}}; m = initialvls[[2]]`?

Comment: @Aisamu that question is about efficiency. this is how to work with thread function, and global variables.

Comment: (1) `Thread` does not have any `HoldXXX` attribute so it's argument is evaluated first. It's argument is `f[{{a,1},{b,2}}]`. `f[whatever]` returns unevaluated. Ergo `Thread` sees `Null`. (2) A simple `Print` statement would have made this clear or at least made it less mysterious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
initialvls = {};
m = 0;
f[x_] := Module[{}, If[x[[2]] > m, m = x[[2]]; initialvls = x];]

Thread[ff[{{a, 1}, {b, 2}}]] /. ff -> f;
initialvls
(* {b, 2} *)
m
(* 2 *)
```

or

```
initialvls = {};
m = 0;
f[x_] := Module[{}, If[x[[2]] > m, m = x[[2]]; initialvls = x];]

Thread[Hold[f][{{a, 1}, {b, 2}}]] // ReleaseHold;
(* {b, 2} *)
m
(* 2 *)
```